# Decode Unicode Keycode to String

Tags: python, unicode, keycode

Using Python, I'm reading lines from a Logfile produced by a Firefox extension. One of the inputs in the log is a number that represents the value returned by Event.keycode() that has been used on a keyup event.

While reading the loglines, I want to convert those keycode values to the char they're representing.

Example logfile line:

```
1338899783924,keyup,[object HTMLInputElement],true,true,false,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,16,undefined,false,undefined,undefined,undefined,false
```

In this case the 16 is the value returned by Event.keycode

Solved this problem already in Java using a scriptengine and converting the value with javascript. Maybe that could be used for python, too?

*Note:*
Python only, the data is already gathered and there is no changing the extension or w/e

Comment: Provide piece of you Logfile, please.

Comment: What character should ``16`` represent?

Answer (score 2):

What about this, assuming the keycode is a Unicode code point ?

```
chr(int(line.split(",")[10]))
```

See also python doc for [chr](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)